# some probability question

Tags: probability

```
Lets say there is a 3 coins. and it start with all front side.
and you roll the dice and do the following. 

1 or 2 : flip left coin
3 or 4 : flip middle one
5 or 6 : flip right one 

problem : find the probability that it become   back,front,front when it roll 3 times
```

so first of all only left one change 3 times : 1/27
fist one flip once and other one flip 2wice : 1/27
first one flip and another coin flip 2wice : 1/27

so 1/9

what you think

Comment: How many dice rolls are there? Three?

Comment: Obviously, the answer will depend on the time of dice rolls.

Comment: When you say "flip" do you mean "turn over" or "toss in the air and see which side faces up where it lands?"  That makes a big difference.

Comment: sorry for my english.. turn over

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can end up with the coins as back, front, front, as you said.

Those three are:

1. Turn over the first coin three times. The probability for this happening is, as you have said, $1/27$.
2. Turn over the first coin once and the second coin twice. This is a bit more tricky, since it can happen in three ways:

   - First, second, second
   - Second, first, second
   - Second, second, first

   The probability of *each* of these is $1/27$, so the total probability that you turn over the first coin once and the second coin twice is $3\cdot 1/27 = 1/9$.
3. Turn over the first coin once and the third coin twice. Again, this can happen in three ways, and the probability of each of them is $1/27$, so the total probability of this event is also $1/9$.

And then you add these three together to get $1/9 + 1/9 + 1/27 = 7/27$.

---

Another way of looking at it is this: After three dice throws, the possible outcomes are the following:

- Back, front, front
- Front, back, front
- Front, front, back
- Back, back, back

Since the three coins are equal in all ways except their order, the probability of each of the three top ones are equal. This means that we can calculate them indirectly once we know the probability of the last event, namely *back, back, back*. So let's calculate that probability.

We need to turn over the first coin (probability $1/3$), the second coin (again $1/3$), and the third coin ($1/3$). The probability that we get to turn them over in a specified order is therefore $1/27$. It can be done in a total of $3\cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ orders, so the probability that we get this end result is $6/27 = 2/9$.

This means that the probability that only one coin is turned upside-down at the end is $1 - 2/9 = 7/9$. Since all the coins are equal, the probability that it is the *first* coin is a third of this, and we get $7/27$.